# Select rows with same column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've a table having data as:

```
C1    ||   C2    || C3  
-------------------
1     || user1   || 2  
2     || user2   || 2   
3     || user3   || 3 
4     || user4   || 3 
5     || user5   || 3  
6     || user6   || 2
```

I want to select all rows which have Column C3 equal values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a derived table to work out the duplicates, and then join back to this:

```
SELECT mt.*
FROM MyTable mt
JOIN
(
  SELECT C3, COUNT(*)
  FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY C3
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) X
ON mt.C3 = X.C3;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e1c7/1)

Obviously, in your example all users have at least one other user with the same C3 value.

Comment: I need your favor can you tell me how to fetch a column C3 using this query?

Comment: I'm not following - `mt.*` will include `C1, C2 and C3`. If you just want C3, then `SELECT mt.C# ...` . Or do you mean you just want to filter `where Mytable.C3 = SomeValue` ? @khanxada 's first answer does that.

Comment: i mean how to fetch column after checking e.g : `if(mysql_num_row($query) > 0) { while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { $c3 = $row['C3']; } }`

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a group-by and figure out the required C3 values, and select them

```
select * 
from table
where c3 in 
(
 select c3, count(c1) as tot
 from table 
 group by c3
 having count(c1)>=2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rows with a particullar value on that column then select * from table where c3='value'
If you want to get listed rows with equal c3 one after other then
Select * from table group by c3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select those rows which have value 3

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE C3=3;
```

Or you want to select rows in which column C3 contain values them:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE C3 IS NOT NULL;
```